# Python OS command

Tags: python, linux, operating-system

I wrote a python program for Kali Linux GONE 64 (Debian 7) . I wrote it so it would run the metasploit database with the commands below. The problem is that i opens all of these commands in different shells. I want to run them all one by one in one shell. How do i do this in python?

```
import os
os.system("service postgresql start")
os.system("wait")
os.system("service metasploit start")
os.system("wait")
os.system("armitage")
```

Comment: Why does this need to be a Python script? Just use a shell script to hold all of these commands.

Comment: What are you expecting `wait` to do? (It probably isn't what you think it does.)

Comment: I added 'wait' hoping that it would stop all the shells from popping up. Also because i wanted to write a python script to do it just for the sake of programming in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("service postgresql start ; wait ; service metasploit start ; wait ; armitagedate", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want putting this into a separate script file, open /bin/sh in a subprocess and feed these commands to its stdin, line by line. You can also pass any parameters this way, if properly quoted.